# wait for ajax call completed then run all test jasmine

Tags: karma-jasmine

I am using jasmine and karma in a simple javascript project with jQuery.
I want my messages are loaded from a json and then execute all the test cases.
it is not waiting for the message load and ended up with many errors.

`urx.localeService.loadJson();`

this method loads a json response and assign the object to window.urx.msg; which is being used in my test cases like

`urx.emailVerification.fail();
expect($("#verifyEmailMsg").html()).toBe(urx.msg["tryAgain"]);`

How can i resolve it?

In my application i have mechanism, when that messaged loaded i publish event and others subscribe to that and it works perfectly.